# Peerblock equivalent for ubuntu

Tags: p2p

Is there a package available in the package manager that provide features similar that peer block?  If yes, which one is the best?

(please, one product by answer)

Answer (score 1):

I use IPblock

Description and installation instructions here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=530183

Comment: Question significantly changed after answer given